# CSS background-color makes two colors

Tags: css, background-color

I'm trying to set my body's background color to a simple grey background but I am getting a two blocks with different greys like this:

[image: two colors]

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  height: 100vmax;
  width: 100vmax;
  background-color: rgb(23, 23, 23);
}

#menuClosed {
  width: 45px;
  height: auto;
}

#menuOpen {
  width: 45px;
  height: auto;
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

#sidebarOpen {
  background-color: rgb(23, 23, 23);
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#sidebarOpen button {
  padding: inherit;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue" defer></script>
  <script src="./app.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <img v-show="sidebar.open === false" @click="sidebar.open = true" src="./assets/navi/menu.png" id="menuClosed">
      <div v-show="sidebar.open === true" id="sidebarOpen">
        <img @click="sidebar.open = false" src="./assets/navi/menu.png" id="menuOpen">
        <p>menu</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

this is my js file

```
Vue.config.devtools = true
var rootvue = new Vue({
    el: "#root",
    data: {
        sidebar: {
            open: false
        }
    }
})
```

Then when i click the menu button it goes away and turns into this
[image: photo]

Comment: Can you create a [MRE] with the HTML code that will show this happening? It's difficult to tell from the CSS alone, there is nothing obvious wrong but we don't know what is being applied where!

Comment: @ZeroTwoooo Can you add a fiddile or something? What's the html code you use?

Comment: HI, @ZeroTwoooo - Welcome. This CSS has some issues / can you break it down into the very most simple situation? Almost everything about this CSS is really scary. Maybe this: filter: brightness(0) invert(1); - is the culprit.

Comment: @sheriffderek i have tried to remove filter: but that didnt change anything.

Comment: Try starting with this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/fus40h1j/

Comment: I've put your code into a snippet (except for the js which won't work here without vue) and it's not happening in this code. Have you found out anything in the element inspector to see what element has the different colour?